# How to replace and word after : when you getting unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to replace any word after `Time:`.

The expression is

```
\Time:.*$
```

I get the error from the title.

I tried With double `/` before and doesn't find anything.

Comment: Why \T? Is this yoir regex string?

Comment: Which tool or programming language are you using? Note that `.*` matches more than a word.

Comment: The direct translation would be `Time:\W*\w+`. Note that `\T` is not available as an escape sequence.

Comment: If you need to only remove a word *after* `Time:` use `(Time:\s*)\w+` and replace with `$1` (or `\1` depending what engine/tool you are using).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Thanks , you're solution worked. I'm using Notepad++ and I have some text files to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\T` is an invalid regex escape sequence, it is not defined in the [Boost regex library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) (NPP uses Boost regex library).

You may use

*Find*: `(Time:\s*)\w+`
*Replace*: `$1`

**Detials**

- `(Time:\s*)` - Capturing group 1: `Time:` and 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

The `$1` refers to the capturing group contents, so `Time:` and whitespaces are not removed.